# Changing background color onclick on a specific table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background color of a specific clicked table row. It also should change it back to the original color. Back and forth from red to green. And it should also check the checkbox. Green = checkbox checked/ Red = checkbox unchecked.

The rows look like this
`<tr id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">`

and for JQUERY I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table tr').click(function(event) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var bcolor = $('.task').css('background-color');

        console.log(id);
        console.log(bcolor);

if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');

            if (bcolor == 'rgb(205, 92, 92)') {
                $('.task').css('background-color', 'green');
            } else {
                $('.task').css('background-color', 'indianred');
            }
        };



    });
});
```

How can I use the `var id = $(this).attr('id');` to change the background color only for the specific clicked row?

Right now it makes every row green by clicking on any of them.

Whole main.php:

Header

```
<?php include 'taskpdo.php';?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Body

```
<body>
    <!-- CONFIRM MESSAGE -->
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
    <div class="msg">
        <?php
            echo $_SESSION['message'];
            unset($_SESSION['message']);
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif?>

    <div class="spacer">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>To Do List</h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Userinformation -->
        <div class="logout">
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
            <p>Welcome<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
            <p><a href="main.php?logout='1'">logout</a></p>
            <?php endif?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Table

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Check</th>
                <th>UID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Num</th>
                <th>Tasks</th> 
                <th>Edit</th>               
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

$tasks = sqlsrv_query($db,
                "SELECT * FROM todo 
                join registrieren  
                on username = ersteller 
                where username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'");
```

Rows

```
$i = 1;
while ($zeile = sqlsrv_fetch_array($tasks)) {
    ?>

            <tr id="<?php echo $zeile['id'] ?>" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $zeile['id'] ?>">

                <td class="task"><input type="checkbox" id="check--<?php echo $zeile['id'] ?>"></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>"> 
                <td class="task" ><?php echo $zeile['uid'] ?></td>
                <td class="task" ><?php echo $zeile['username'] ?></td>
                <td class="task" ><?php echo $zeile['id'] ?></td>
                <td class="task" id="<?php echo $zeile['id'] ?>" ><?php echo $zeile['task'] ?></td>  

                <td class="task" onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $zeile['id'] ?>)">
                    <form method="post" action="main.php">
                        <button type="submit" name="edit">                                                                
                            Edit
                         </button>
                         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>"> 
                         <input type="hidden" name="task" value="<?php echo $zeile['task']; ?>">    
                    </form>
                </td>


                <td class="task" onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $zeile['id'] ?>)">    
                    <form method="post" action="main.php" >
                         <button type="submit" name="delete">                                          
                            Delete
                         </button>
                         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>">
                    </form>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <?php
$i++;}
?>


        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Buttons

```
    <form method="post" action="main.php" class="input_form">


        <input type="hidden" name="ersteller" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>">     


        <?php 

        if ($update == true): ?>  
        <input type="text" name="task" class="task_input" value="<?php echo $task ?>">      
        <button type="submit" name="update" id="add_btn" class="add_btn">Update</button>
        <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">


        <?php else: ?>
        <input type="text" name="task" class="task_input">
        <button type="submit" name="addtask" id="add_btn" class="add_btn">Add Task</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">       
        <?php endif ?>

    </form>   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're already using `this` to get the `id` of the row, so using the `id` from that to get a reference to `this` again is about as redundant as it gets. Just change `$('.task')` to `$(this)` and your code will work.

Comment: If I change  `$('.task')` to `$(this)` the background color don't change anymore.

Comment: That's most likely because the `bcolor == 'rgb(205, 92, 92)'` check fails. Could you please add your HTML to the question so we can debug it properly.

Comment: Also note that this question has nothing to do with PHP or SQL Server so I removed those tags

Comment: Just the `table`. Also note that we don't want the PHP logic, just the HTML output. Copy it from View Source in your browser if needed

Comment: I've added a bit much, right?  But I still don't understand why the ```bcolor == 'rgb(205, 92, 92)'``` stop working after changing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use toggleClass of jQuery:

```
// css for put in your element
.common-class {
    background-color: #ff0000; // replace for your color
}

.highlight-class {
    background-color: #0000ff !important; // replace for your color
}

$('your-selector').toggleClass('highlight-class'); // jQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

Bensilson's answer helped me and i want to clarify what i have done:

I delete the `class='task'`inside the `<td>` and put it into the `<tr>` - Tag.

I've done a `.highlighttask{background-color: green !important}` inside the css.

And inside the js i've done

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".table tr").on('click', function() {
        var checked = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
        checked.prop('checked', !checked.is(':checked'));
        $(this).toggleClass('highlighttask');

    });

});
```

Now it overrights the background-color on a specific row AND it checks the checkbox of the specific row.
Thanks!